# TortoiseSVN put a password on SVN repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to make a new SVN repository on server and use it from local PC to make code changes on server.

I has been working with SVN, and GIT, and all of times, server support make a user aceess and other part of configuration. In this time i want to create a repository myself.

I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows7 PC.

Question is that, how to protect SVN repository from clone, take, updates?

I see in SVN repository is folder `conf` and files `passwd` , `authz`. What is theses files and how to put password, username for them?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at those two files they have examples in them, all you have to do is uncomment them. Here are the main steps to get you set up:

In the passwd file, simply add the following for each user:

```
<username> = <password>
```

In authz, at the bottom of the file, add the following lines which will grant read and write access to the specified user for your entire directory:

```
[/]
<username> = rw
```

The final step is to go into svnserve.conf and uncomment the following lines, which specifies you want to use the authz and passwd files as your authorization and password databases:

```
authz-db = authz
password-db = passwd
```

additionally, by default anonymous users have read access to your repository, you can add the following to change that

```
anon-access = none
```

Comment: Ok, tnx. Test it to morrow.